# Creating users from a CSV to AD

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a script that will take a CSV with the fields and create a user in AD in a specific OU with that info.

```
Sam,Firstname,LastName,MobilePhone,mail
SYS12345678,Test,Test,05555551111,aa@contoso.com
SYS12534644,Test,Test,05555551155,bb@contoso.com
```

After users creating I want to export CSV file like below.

```
Username :SYS12345678 Password : Ja1304Sp
Username :SYS25453234 Password : Ja1304Hg
```

I have a few questions:

1. I need to check like if a user exists before creating them.
2. Copy the MobilePhone attribute to the ipphone attribute without leading zero. (if Mobile Phone is `05555551111` then ipphone would be `5555551111`)
3. Copy the `SamAccountname` attribute without prefix `SYS`, to both `EmployeeID` and `pager` attributes.

When attempting to run script I got the following error messages:

> New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pager'.
>       At line:45 char:15
>
> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Username' under: 'DC=contoso,DC=local'.
>       At line:47 char:22

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$UserList = Import-CSV -Path C:\Export\CreateUsers.csv

$targetOU = 'OU=USERS,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=local'

$upnDomain = 'contoso.local'

$Path = "C:\Export\UserOutput.csv"


foreach ($Person in $UserList)
{



$Password = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $Person.Firstname.Substring(0, 2), (Get-Date).ToString("ddMM"), $Person.Lastname.Substring(0, 2)

$useritems = @{
GivenName = $Person.Firstname
Surname = $Person.LastName
Department = "TEST"
AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -force
ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
Enabled = $true
Description = "TEST"
DisplayName = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
Name = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
SamAccountName = $Person.Sam
Office = "XXX"
employeeID = $Person.TempEmployeeID
title = "XXX"
initials = $Person.initials
company = "Contoso"
EmailAddress = $Person.mail
Manager = "XXXX"
IPPhone = $Person.MobilePhone.Replace("^0","")
EmployeeID = $Person.Sam.Replace("SYS","")
Pager = $Person.Sam.Replace("SYS","")
UserPrincipalName = $Person.Sam+$upnDomain  

}

New-ADUser  @useritems -Path $targetOU

Add-Adgroupmember -identity "Test_Group" -Members $Person.Sam

Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "Username:,$Username,Password:,$Password"

}
```

Comment: I m assuming the errors are self explanatory here. New-aduser contains no parameter called pager. There is no user with samaccount sys1111222222.

Comment: first of all, you have to handle these exceptions using try/catch. so that if any error occurs , it should proceed with the remaining objects. Secondly, you should check the properties and methods available using get-member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are pretty clear on what's wrong. `New-ADUser` doesn't have parameters for `Pager` and `IPPhone` (cmdlet failed before noticing this), see [New-ADUser @ Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) for list of parameters. Try using `otherAttributes` to set them.

You can use `Get-ADUser` to search for the samaccountname before creating. If it doesn't return anything -> continue. Try:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$UserList = Import-CSV -Path C:\Export\CreateUsers.csv
$targetOU = 'OU=USERS,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$upnDomain = 'contoso.local'
$Path = "C:\Export\UserOutput.csv"

foreach ($Person in $UserList) {

    #If username does not exist
    if(-not(Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Person.Sam)'")) {
        $Password = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $Person.Firstname.Substring(0, 2), (Get-Date).ToString("ddMM"), $Person.Lastname.Substring(0, 2)

        $useritems = @{
            GivenName = $Person.Firstname
            Surname = $Person.LastName
            Department = "TEST"
            AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -force
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            Enabled = $true
            Description = "TEST"
            DisplayName = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
            Name = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
            SamAccountName = $Person.Sam
            Office = "XXX"
            employeeID = $Person.TempEmployeeID
            title = "XXX"
            initials = $Person.initials
            company = "Contoso"
            EmailAddress = $Person.mail
            Manager = "XXXX"
            EmployeeID = $Person.Sam.Replace("SYS","")
            OtherAttributes = @{
                Pager = $Person.Sam.Replace("SYS","")
                IPPhone = $Person.MobilePhone -replace '^0'
            }
            UserPrincipalName = "$($Person.Sam)@$upnDomain" 
        }

        New-ADUser @useritems -Path $targetOU

        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test_Group" -Members $Person.Sam

        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "Username: $($Person.Sam) Password: $Password"

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks man. My last question is : how canI add automatically SYS prefix for SamAccountName attribute  ?  e.g SamAccountName = SYS+$Person.Sam Am I correct ?

Comment: Huh? You could use `"SYS$($Person.Sam)"`, but why would you? Your CSV-file already contains SYS-prefix, which is why you remove it on EmployeeID and Pager...

Comment: I am getting an error:  Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'SYS1111222222' under: 'DC=contoso,DC=local'.
At line:11 char:23
+     if(-not(Get-ADUser <<<<  -Identity ($Person.Sam))) {
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SYS1111222222:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'SYS1111222222' under: 'DC=contoso,DC=local'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Fixed now. Was writing from memory, so forgot that cmdlet throws terminating error for non-existing Identity. Changed it to a `Filter`-query instead (cleaner than try/catch-logic).

Comment: Now I have another questions.  its still displaying ipphone attribute with zero leading such as 0555 555 55 55.  2-  I have checked userlogonname in AD Users I can see as SYS1111222222contoso.local

Comment: Try now. `Replace()` doesn't use regex-patterns like "^0", so I changed to `-replace`, and you where missing a @ in `$upndomain` (fixed it in the hashtable instead).